# Need some help with Bra-Ket notation (specifically orthogonality in bra-ket notation)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation

I'm reading notes from a friend of mine taking a quantum mechanics class, and I see something I don't quite get.

$$\left<x_i|x_j\right> = \delta_{ij}.$$

The notes say this implies orthogonality. Generally, the dot product of two orthogonal vectors is just zero, yes? So delta here = 0, but what exactly does $\delta_{ij}$ represent? Thanks in advance for any help and feel free to ask for more details. $x_i$ and $x_j$ are elementary basis vectors.

Comment: So that you know, that symbol is called the kronecker delta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). It's $0$ when $i \neq j$, and 1 when $i=j$. In other words, the "dot product" of $|x_i\rangle$ and $|x_j\rangle$ is zero unless $i=j$, in which case it's 1, just like with "usual" vectors.

---

**EDIT:** Of course, as @user12262 points out, the dot product of two vectors is only 1 when the vectors themselves have a length of 1 each. (We then say that such vectors are "normalised"). If the vectors have arbitrary length, then the condition for normalisation is actually:

$$\langle x_i|x_j\rangle = \delta_{ij} \sqrt{\langle x_i|x_i\rangle} 
\sqrt{\langle x_j|x_j\rangle} ,$$

where the terms on the right-hand-side are the "lengths" of each of the vectors.

Comment: Philip: "_[...] just like with "usual" vectors._" -- The given formula $$\langle x_j | x_k \rangle = \delta_{jk}$$ also implies that any and all $|x_j\rangle$ (of index $j$ range under consideration) are separately **normalized**; i.e. $$\langle x_j | x_j \rangle = 1.$$ Such [orthonormal vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality#Definition) are of course often convenient to use. (@Tolemus M´s OP calls them "elementary basis vectors".) Orthogonality without implying normalization: $$\langle a_j | a_k \rangle = \delta_{jk}\,\sqrt{\langle a_j|a_j \rangle \, \langle a_k|a_k \rangle}.$$

Comment: @user12262 You're right, of course. I was just keeping it simple since the OP's question seemed more conceptual, but you're right that it's a little sloppy. I'll edit to include it :) Thanks!

Comment: Technically what you edited in isn't equivalent to @user12262's equation; consider the case where one or both vectors vanish.

Comment: @J.G. That's true. I've taken them over to the other side :)